# Can't reassign an object's attribute to another existing object

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

So, as part of my programming studies, I am making a disjoint set data structure. However, one method requires fetching two nodes, and if they aren't the same nodes, joining the nodes. This is supposed to be done by setting one node's parent attribute to be the other node. However, after stepping through the method with a debugger, the parent value never changes. For reference, some of the code:

```
class Node:
    # a bare bones node class representing an entry in the  disjoint set
    # track the ids as a static variable
    id = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = Node.id
        Node.id += 1
        self.parent = None
        self.rank = 0
```

and the problem code itself, a method in the disjoint set class:

```
    def union(self, u, v):
        # the union operation is used to join two components into one
        # this implementation uses the component's ranks to optimize the union operation
        # in this varient, the component with the lesser rank is attached to the root with the greater rank

        # the find method searches for a particular node, and returns a Node object
        # (an instance of the above class)
        u_root = self.find(u)
        v_root = self.find(v)

        # if u and v's root are the same, they are in the same component
        # therefore, end the operation because they are already merged
        if u_root.id == v_root.id:
            return

        # to simplify coding, we force the u root to always be the root of lower rank
        if u_root.rank > v_root.rank:
            u_root, v_root = v_root, u_root

        # merge u root into v root
        u_root.parent = v_root
        # the offending bit of code that isn't working as intended

        # if the two roots share the same rank, you can't just add one onto the other
        if v_root.rank == u_root.rank:
            v_root.rank += 1
```

I suspect I am making assumptions about how variable assignments work in Python, especially when concerning Python objects. I thought variables and attributes that are assigned a Python object treated it like a reference, and any variable referencing the same object could edit it. However, I am definitely at an impasse and need some direction.

Comment: When you step through in the debugger - are you saying that the line ``u_root.parent = v_root`` is executing but that u_root.parent is still None after the line.

Is ``u_root.parent`` a property and not an attribute (maybe ?)

Comment: It sounds like you are expecting a `+=` operation to modify an `int` value in-place, but `int` values are immutable. It's true that `x` and `y` could refer to the same `int` object, but `x += 1` is really `x = x.__iadd__(1)`, and since `int.__iadd__` isn't even defined, it further reduces to `x = x.__add__(1)`, which simply creates a *new* `int` value and assigns that to `x`, leaving `y` to refer to the original value.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 So when I step through with the debugger, after `u_root.parent = v_root` is called, `u_root.parent` is still assigned a value of `None`. I understand that a Python property is an attribute where getters and setters are used to control access to the value, but the root object is an instance of the bare bones Node class, so there are no values using getters/setters (unless I'm mistaking what a property in Python is). Or are you saying I should use getters/setters to modify this value?

Comment: You don't need to use getters/setters - i was just wondering if you were using them, since they could be stopping you setting some values; is ``v_root`` definitely not ``None`` ?

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 the value of `v_root` is definitely not `None`

Comment: It is strange - I would need to see all the code - and be able to run it myself to get to the bottom of it, as nothing jumps out - Anyway that you can package up the code - and then point me to a specific test cases that is causing this to fail ?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/MisturDust319/algorithms-python/blob/master/graphs/union_find.py) is the source for this particular example on GitHub. No test cases, just sort of manual debugging. The union operation is supposed to take two Node ids, retrieve the corresponding Node objects from a dictionary, and join the node with the smaller rank to the node with the greater rank by setting the node of greater rank to be it's parent, which appears to be the point of failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I was writing unit tests for the code to help with debugging, the code started working. I definitely changed some code while writing the tests, but I'm not entirely sure what got things working. But it's working, and unless this issue comes up again, I'm satisfied.